# Waiving PMI on initial conventional mortgage loan

Tags: united-states, mortgage, pmi

I am about to close a mortgage loan for a **HUD** property which I had originally opted for a **USDA Rural @ 3.25%** for a sale price if **$135,500** for **30 years**. I just got the bank appraisal which states its value at **$157,000**.

The current **Conventional** loan rate is at **3.875%** and they ask for **5%** down payment.

If I put in a down payment of **$15,000** for the **conventional** loan, would I be able to automatically get rid of the Mortgage Insurance or do I still need to put in 20%+ down payment?

Should I just stick to my 3.25% USDA Rural loan then?

Comment: Why don't you ask the lender? They would provide you with the most accurate information regarding their requirements and terms and conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In general, PMI is required if you put less than 20% down on the **sale price** of the home, not the appraised value.  If you go with conventional, in general after one year you can appraise the home *again* and if the mortgage amount is less than 80% of the new appraised value you can request the PMI to be removed.

If I were you, I would be going for the USDA program.